# python filtering list of dict by dict containing several key-value pairs as conditions

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter, matching

my example data:

```
list_of_dict =[{'cena': 23, 'nazwa': 'item1', 'param': 'pampam'},
               {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2', 'param': 'iko'   },
               {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2a','param': 'ik2'   },
               {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2b','param': 'ik2'   },
               {'cena': 17, 'nazwa': 'item3', 'param': 'etr'   },
               {'cena': 17, 'nazwa': 'item4', 'param': 'asdf'  }]

conditions =   {'cena': 26, 'param': 'ik2' }
```

I tried:

```
if conditions in list_of_dict:
    do_something()
```

it works, but only when whole conditions dict (every key) matches the one from dict list, I mean:

```
In [1]: exampleSet =      [{  'type' : 'type1', 'k' : 'kval'},
   ...:                    {  'type' : 'type2', 'k' : 'kv2' },
   ...:                    {  'type' : 'type2', 'k' : 'k3'  },
   ...:                    {  'type' : 'type3', 'k' : 'k3'  }]
   ...: 
   ...: conditions =       {  'type' : 'type1', 'k' : 'kval' }
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: conditions in exampleSet
   ...: 
Out[1]: True
In [2]: conditions =       {  'type' : 'type1' }

In [3]: conditions in exampleSet
Out[3]: False
```

while I am trying to match dictionaries with key-value pairs specified, (regardless of values/existence of unspecified ones) so

```
In [4]: exampleSet =      [{  'type' : 'type1', 'k' : 'kval'},
   ...:                    {  'type' : 'type2', 'k' : 'kv2' },
   ...:                    {  'type' : 'type2', 'k' : 'k3'  },
   ...:                    {  'type' : 'type3', 'k' : 'k3'  }]
   ...: 
   ...: conditions =       {  'type' : 'type2' }
   ...:
   ...: my_wanted_match( exampleSet, conditions )
```

has to return:

```
                     [{  'type' : 'type2', 'k' : 'kv2' },
                      {  'type' : 'type2', 'k' : 'k3'  }]
```

as a result.

can anyone gimme some hints on how to achieve this?

Comment: I once answered a question that basically boils down to exactly the same problem, if I understand your question correctly: [emulating the behavior of findWhere() in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553060/emulating-the-behavior-of-findwhere-in-python/23553240)

Answer (score 6):

It is a `filter()` you want - you want to filter your list-of-dicts based on some condition; returning only the entries that match all criteria.

```
>>> list_of_dict =[{'cena': 23, 'nazwa': 'item1', 'param': 'pampam'},
...                {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2', 'param': 'iko'   },
...                {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2a','param': 'ik2'   },
...                {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2b','param': 'ik2'   },
...                {'cena': 17, 'nazwa': 'item3', 'param': 'etr'   },
...                {'cena': 17, 'nazwa': 'item4', 'param': 'asdf'  }]
```

Set conditions:

```
>>> conditions = {'param':'iko'}
```

And do a one-line filter:

```
>>> filter(lambda item: all((item[k]==v for (k,v) in conditions.iteritems())), list_of_dict)
[{'cena': 26, 'param': 'iko', 'nazwa': 'item2'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
>>> list_of_dict =[{'cena': 23, 'nazwa': 'item1', 'param': 'pampam'},
...                {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2', 'param': 'iko'   },
...                {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2a','param': 'ik2'   },
...                {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2b','param': 'ik2'   },
...                {'cena': 17, 'nazwa': 'item3', 'param': 'etr'   },
...                {'cena': 17, 'nazwa': 'item4', 'param': 'asdf'  }]
>>> 
>>> conditions =   {'cena': 26, 'param': 'ik2' }
>>> [d for d in list_of_dict if all((k in d and d[k] == v) for k, v in conditions.items())]
[{'cena': 26, 'param': 'ik2', 'nazwa': 'item2a'}, {'cena': 26, 'param': 'ik2', 'nazwa': 'item2b'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This iterates through each dictionary in `list_of_dict` and returns those that have matching key value pairs to each condition.

```
matches = [one_dict for one_dict in list_of_dict if
           all(key in one_dict and conditions[key] == one_dict[key] 
               for key in conditions.keys())]
>>> matches
[{'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2a', 'param': 'ik2'},
 {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2b', 'param': 'ik2'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`set`s come in handy here<sup>*</sup>:

```
has_match = any(set(condition.items()) <= set(d.items()) for d in listOfDict)
```

or for your second part:

```
the_matches = [
    d
    for d in listOfDict
    if set(condition.items()) <= set(d.items())
]
```

[`<=`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) is the subset operator when applied to sets:

> `issubset(other)`
>   `set <= other`
>
> Test whether every element in the set is in other.

<sup><sup>*</sup> *provided you can ensure your values are hashable, ie not lists or dicts*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_wanted_match(example_set, conditions):
    conditions = conditions.items()
    match = []
    for e in example_set:
        if all([c in set(e.items()) for c in conditions]):
            match.append(e)
    return match
```

or simply:

```
match = [e for e in example_set
         if all([c in set(e.items()) for c in set(conditions.items())])]
```

Comment: `set` will throw if any of `e.values()` are not hashable, sadly

Answer (score -1):

```
list_of_dict =[{'cena': 23, 'nazwa': 'item1', 'param': 'pampam'},
               {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2', 'param': 'iko'   },
               {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2a','param': 'ik2'   },
               {'cena': 26, 'nazwa': 'item2b','param': 'ik2'   },
               {'cena': 17, 'nazwa': 'item3', 'param': 'etr'   },
               {'cena': 17, 'nazwa': 'item4', 'param': 'asdf'  }]

>Answers
 --------

res=list(filter(lambda list_of_dict:list_of_dict['cena']== 26 and list_of_dict['param']== 'ik2',list_of_dict))

for i in range(0,len(res)):
    if 'item2b' in res[i].values() :
        print(res[i])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).